# Request not getting values of properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

This repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> { }
```

And this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    // Get All Users
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Create a new User
    @PostMapping("/users")
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And here is the request:
[image]

For some reason it's not getting the "name" value from the body, so it returns that error. I need the field "name" to be the id (string) not auto generated.

Comment: Add getters and setters to your entity. Or a constructor annotated with JsonCreator and its arguments annotated with JsonProperty.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I seems the property "name" is some kind of protected property, I changed it to 
"username" and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Generate getters and setters for your User Entity:

```
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
```

This should solve your 400 error, I reproduced your code and it worked for me